# What does this loss signify in [num_steps, loss, _] = sess.run(.......)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am working with the VGGish model and I was reviewing the last piece of code which does the training of the data and then prints the loss after each step. I am not sure what does this loss represents. Please tell me what is finds.

```
for _ in range(FLAGS.num_batches):
      (features, labels) = _get_examples_batch(spectrogram, mice_data)
      [num_steps, loss, _] = sess.run(
        # here the first array that we are passing in is called fetches
        # it is a list of graph elements
        [global_step_tensor, loss_tensor, train_op],
          # one has to be of the form of a tensor and the other in the form of a numpy array
          feed_dict={features_tensor: features, labels_tensor: labels})
      print('Step %d: loss %g' % (num_steps, loss))
```

Does this loss tell me how many times does my model predicts the correct classification divided by the total attempts? But if that is the case, then the loss should be less than 1 always. But I got the following output when i run my code 10 times -

```
Audio shape: (31710903,), Sliced audio shape: (5637, 6250)
(310035, 257)
(5637, 55, 257)
Step 1: loss 40.9978
Step 2: loss 21.1056
Step 3: loss 11.8406
Step 4: loss 5.06641
Step 5: loss 1.9772
Step 6: loss 1.06847
Step 7: loss 0.630566
Step 8: loss 0.470541
Step 9: loss 0.392228
Step 10: loss 0.311321
```

Comment: The loss is simply the expression which is sought to be minimized with gradient descent or other algorithms. With the details you provided so far, we can't tell you further. It could be a mean squared error, cross-entropy, etc, and we would need to know your model to give an insightful answer.

Comment: @nanofarad my model talks about cross entry so I think it represents the cross-entropy. But why are the values greater than 1 in the beginning?

Comment: Under a common definition of cross entropy using conditional logarithms, there's no mathematical reason why the value has to be less than 1. It is also likely that your loss is the *sum* of per-example cross entropies over the whole batch, rather than the *average*.